# Android: Reading specific nodes from XML without parsing entire document

Tags: android, xml

I'm feeling kind of dumb here. I am storing sets of data that are always organized at a top level by Chapter > Scene > Dialogue. Dialogue always has several attributes and sometimes has additional data that is also always stored in an organized hierarchy (Sets of conditions, or sets of choices, each with attributes of their own to be read). Imagine a choose-your-own-adventure book and all of its rules being stored in an XML document. This seemed like the best way to store it, I'd welcome a contradiction.

I will always start on Chapter 1, Scene 1, Dialogue 1. Each dialogue, either through attributes or conditions, will always direct me to a single new node, for example, Chapter 3, Scene 2, Dialogue 8. I will never have to parse the entire document looking for chapter, scene, or dialogue tags. However, I do want to parse the given Dialogue node to look at its included sets of conditions or choices.

I can not for the life of me find how to specify, in Android, the equivalent of:

```
XMLResourceParser parser = getResources().getXml((R.xml.script).getChild[CHAPTER][SCENE][DIALOGUE]);
```

And while I could parse the entire document every time and iterate off to match my indexes and know where I am, that seems completely uncalled for. Any thoughts? Everywhere I look people are looking for solutions to problems that require reading the entire document and the answer is always on how to use the parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not clear exactly what you are looking for.  If you want to read in an a xml file, and you only care about a few nodes within the file, you can use a SAX or pull parser to only listen for the nodes that you care about.  This article [xml in Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/) has examples of both.

If you care about the whole document, but just want an easy way to navigate to navigate to a particular element in the tree, couple of options.  You can parse the XML into a dom document (the third option in the article above) and use functions like [getElementsByTagName](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29) to walk the tree.

Or, you could look into using XPath.  See this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-descr.html) for an overview.

Comment: I guess a simpler way to put it is that instead of identifying nodes by their name I want to specify nodes by their number in relation to their depth, as if it were an array. In AS3 I have a type called XMLList that lets me do this with a function getChildAt(index) that returns just the XML object at that index, so I can pare the total document down a lot before parsing if I know the index number I want.

Comment: You should be able to do something similar in XPath.  I'm not sure of your XML structure, but it would make sense to have each chapter, scene, etc have a number attribute.  Then you could do something like `/chapter[@number = '3']/scene[@number = '2']/dialogue[@name = '8']`  If you really want to do it based on position, you can do that also with the `position()` function. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths

Comment: I am getting XPath to work, but it seems like the background functions are effectively still parsing the document to get what I'm asking for, which I suppose makes sense and may explain why my problem seemed weird. 

I guess at the end of the day I will make two functions to do it both ways, and try and see which one is more efficient. Either way - XPath essentially solves what I was asking for, for better or worse - so thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there is a way to get around that.  You can't find things in a text document without first doing some amount of parsing first.  It should hopefully minimize the amount of parsing that needs to be done though.